# WPF Navigation Window with more controls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I'm learning WPF, and NavigationWindow in particular. I want to add stuff to the window, like a status bar, a favorite bar, etc.
Unfortunately when I try adding anything, I get an error.

I'm hoping there might be a way that pages can be bookmarked as someone browses between them; let the user drag pages up to a favorite bar.

Something similar with the status bar; I'd like to have page specific information on the status bar, without having to have it on each individual page.

Is this possible with a navigation window, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Edit:

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Nav Test" Height="300" Width="300" Source="Window1.xaml" >
    <StatusBar></StatusBar> ' The type 'NavigationWindow' does not support direct content.
</NavigationWindow>
```

Update, What I went with:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Tracks" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="265*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Name="Menu1" />
        <Frame Grid.Row="2" Name="Frame1" Source="PageSearchResults.xaml" />
        <ToolBar Grid.Row="1" Name="ToolBar1" >
            <Button Content="+" Name="Button1" />
        </ToolBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I ended up putting the status bar on the individual pages, so that I can more easily change what's displayed from page to page, but the tool bar behaves nicely with the frame.

Comment: Can you post your code and what the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to WPF too but I believe a NavigationWindow needs a starting "Page" and that all your controls should be added to that page, not the NavigationWindow it's self.  You could add a frame to the start page and do your navigations to other pages from that frame while the start page could contain your favorite bar, status bar etc.

Comment: The only problem with that is that I would have to have the status and navigation on each page. might not be the worse thing with the status bar, the navigation/favorite bar wouldnt be practical I dont thing. I'm looking into frames though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your own content apart from the Page, then don't use NavigationWindow. Use a regular Window instead. Then, in the place where you want your navigation content, add a [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx). Frame supports all the same navigation you can do with a NavigationWindow (in fact, a NavigationWindow is basically just a Window with a Frame filling it).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up going with. Seems to work alright so far. Now just trying to figure out bookmarking visited Pages. Thanks for the reply